# Wasteland2: what happens if I dont finish Tinker?

Tags: wasteland-2-directors-cut

I think nobody tried that? as I cant find the answer..

Tinker asks us to leave and it has plans to Binh...

Or may be it was not planned/scripted and nothing will happen and Tinker will remain there forever?

Btw, I saw we can come back later to save her, that could mean Tinker will remain there forever...

Answer (score 1):

Tinker will remain there forever. If you ignore her nothing much will happen, there are no follow up events, that's why you can't find anything about it.